# Floated element keeps full "original" width of inner narrower block element

Tags: css, css-float

I have a possibly simple question.

I have a floated element with a block element inside.

Adding text inside the block element expands the block element horizontally as well as the parent float (like it's supposed to).

If I add a width to the inner block element, the text is wrapped and the block element becomes that width.

However, the floated element is still as wide as the block element would be without a width set on it, where I would expect it to shrink down to the set width of the block element.

Does the text have an invisible width?

Here's a very simple fiddle that shows what I'm talking about.

http://jsfiddle.net/bup88/

```
.thumbs li
{
   float:left;
  border:solid 1px black;
}
.thumbs div
{
  width:20%;
  border:solid 1px red;
}



<ul class="thumbs">
  <li>
 <img src="http://placehold.it/250X250" /> 
  <div>
    some text some text some text some text some text some textsome text some text
  </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Why does the floated element stay as wide as the block element would without the width rule?

Comment: Looks good to me. What's your exact question?

Comment: Are you talking about the space in between the image and copy? If yes, make the image `display:block:`. If no, what Praveen said.

Comment: The img and the div width are both way smaller than the li width.

What is keeping the li that width? LOL

Why doesn't the li element(the float) collapse horizontally?

Comment: Sorry for all the edits.  Just wanted to make it as clear as possible.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I think the edits make his question clearer now. I'm seeing what he is describing in his fiddle.

Comment: Divs are block level elements so they take up the full width. If you change your fiddle so that they're inline you'll see it shrinks to fit the text. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/bup88/3/

Comment: Thanks all that makes sense. There's no width declared, so the parser finds the width of the parent first THEN finds the child widths.  Very interesting. 

Do you guys know of any way to force the text to wrap to the images width without declaring a width on the li float?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set width:20%; to a block wich parent has no width for reference.

What i find strange is to see that, because `<li>` is floatting, you still get  this 20% of a `<li>` that somehow browsers sizes at average size of the div itself ?
So in the end , the div takes 100% of its content, then resize  to 20% of itself width.

**If `<li>` has a width in CSS, then it wraps as it should.**

**if div has a value, exept % value, it wraps**

It bugs cause your CSS is not coherent somehow :)

http://jsfiddle.net/bup88/4/

Comment: Thanks!  That fiddle helped.

Comment: @Nickthemagicman Oh, I see what you were asking now. I think the way you asked the question confused most.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a CSS expert, so if any below assumptions are incorrect someone let me know.

I think it's due to your usage of a percentage `width` on the block element, which will look at the parent element (the floated one) for the width value it should be using with the percentage to compute a final width.

In order to figure out this percentage width, I'm guessing the layout engine is first computing how wide the block element would be without the percentage rule, then setting the floated parent element to that width as it would if the percentage rule were not present. Now that the floated element has a defined width, the child block element can have its percentage width computed. This computation won't affect the width of the floated parent element, however, as that is already laid out.

Setting the width to something definite like `px`, or changing the layout type from block to inline (like j08691 suggested) will make it behave more how you expected.

Answer (score 1):

CHANGE THAT WAY:

```
.thumbs div{
  float:right;/* UPDATE WITH */
  width:20%;/* CHANGE WITH THE SIZE THAT YOU WANT FOR THE DIV */
  border:solid 1px red;
}
.thums img{
  float:left;
}
```

Than all will fit horizontal.

Comment: Understood that adding a width is best practice and that I could also use Javascript also to do this.

However, I'm trying to understand what is going on from a theoretical standpoint. 

Why is the width still present? It's like inline elements ALWAYS keep their width no matter what the text is doing?

Thanks again for the help.

Comment: If you don't use width tag the text will occupy all the space that it find until the end of the window or the parent width. If you use width the text will be formatted in the size that you want.Try to leave only one word in jsFiddle and the size will be only that of the img.

Answer (score 1):

A better option would be to use inline-block on the child elements of `thumbs` this allows the text to fill a space as big or small as you need. If you remove the width, it will fill the remaining space.

```
.thumbs img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  zoom: 1;
}
.thumbs div
{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width:20%;
  border:solid 1px red;
  zoom: 1;
}
```